# Geometry question with squares

Tags: geometry

Apologies for a crude drawing, but let's say we have a figure:

[image]

Where the square has the points $B(0,0)$, $A(1,0)$, $D(1,1)$, $C(0,1)$, the length of $EB$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. How can we prove that if we draw a ray from $E$ parallel to $BD$ (the diagnal of the square) it will intersect $A$?

It seems intuitively obvious to me but I do not understand how to make the proof. Thank you.

EDIT: One of the given things was not actually given, I assumed it incorrectly. I apologize. I've removed it.

Comment: The proposition is only true if $\angle AEB$ is  a right angle.

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Clearly, $|EA| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ so $\Delta AEB$ is an isosceles right angle triangle. So $\angle EAB = 45^\circ$. Since $\angle EAB = \angle ABD$, we can conclude that $AE // BD$.

Comment: What if we didn't know that angle AEB = $90^\circ$? Could we still prove it?t

Comment: No, it may or may not be parallel in that case. If we don't know $\angle AEB$ or $\angle ABE$, then the line segment $[BE]$ can move around. Suppose $E$, $B$ and $C$ are linear. Then abviously, $AE // BD$ is a false argument.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the two diagonals AC and BD which intersect in O, then show that $\triangle COD\cong \triangle BEA$.

Answer (score 0):

With $EB=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, $\angle AEB=90^\circ$ and $AB=1$ given, you can apply Pythagoras' theorem to $\triangle AEB$ and calculate $AE=\sqrt{1^2-\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=EB$, so $\triangle AEB$ is isosceles, and $\angle EAB=\angle EBA=45^\circ$. Because $\angle ABD=45^\circ$ too, we can notice that $\angle EAB$ and $\angle ABD$ are 'alternate angles' and so it follows that $EA\parallel BD$.

Comment: What if we didn't know that angle AEB = 90∘? Could we still prove it?

Comment: Obviously not. All we would then know is that $E$ lies on the circle with the center in $B$ and radius $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. For some points $E$ on that circle, $EA\parallel BD$, for others $EA\not\parallel BD$. Actually, if you try to find where $E$ must be so that $EA\parallel BD$, you will find out that $\angle AEB$ *has* to be $90^\circ$.